# How to check for null/whitespace/NA values while selecting in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT column_name1,column_name2,column_name3,column_name4 from table_name
```

How do i do multiple checks for all the coulmn_name?

for now i am checking for NULL to return "Empty String" using COALESCE.

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(column_name1,'')as Column_name1,
COALESCE(column_name2,'')as Column_name2,
COALESCE(column_name3,'')as Column_name3,
COALESCE(column_name4,'')as Column_name4, from table_name
```

My requirement is to return "Empty String" where ever the values are NULL or WhiteSpaces or NA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `case`:

```
select (case when column_name1 is null or ltrim(rtrim(column_name1)) in ('NA', '') then ''
             else column_name1
       end)
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE, ISNULL, COALESCE can all be used in combination as necessary.

If you  are using the 2012 or later versions of SQL Server, there are 2 more options to choose from to simplify CASE statement:
1. IIF
2. CHOOSE

Check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21327.t-sql-simplified-case-expression.aspx) link for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT coalesce (nullif (rtrim(ltrim(column_name1)), 'N/A'), '') 
   AS column_name1 
FROM table_name
```

Found an answer.. is this correct way?? i mean does this works exactly to the requirement?